# I want to get image size, width, height without uploading image

Tags: jquery

i am trying this code but get only image size not image width.

```
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {

    var size = this.files[0].size;
    var w = this.files[0].width;
    var sizeKB = Math.round(size/1024);
    alert(sizeKB+'KB');
    alert(w);

});

<input type="file" id="myFile" />
```

anybody have solution?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-on-upload-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

write this code on image change event

```
         var _URL = window.URL;
        function checkImage(fileObj){
        var file, img;
        if ((file = fileObj.files[0])) {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                alert("Width:" + this.width + "   Height: " + this.height);//this will give you image width and height and you can easily validate here....
            };
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }
    }
```

this will give height and width both on load of image

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the browser you are testing this code under [supports the HTML5 File API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi). Here's a [nice article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) you may take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an image using raw JavaScript. You will need an alternate by using a flash uploader of some kind like Uploadify.

Comment: Yes, you can if the browser supports the HTML 5 File API and in the future all of them will support it.

Comment: Yes, but not all browsers currently support HTML5, IE is still dragging us down (also outdated browsers).

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery:

```
$(this).prop('files')[0].size
```