# Prompt width and height of image being uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I am looking for some method to prompt the width and height of the image being uploaded using an asp file upload control. Following is the code I am using to prompt message for file size. I just want to add the width and height of the image being uploaded using that upload control. Please take a note that I can't use javascript DOM here like `img.clientWidth` as there is no such html object to call it.

Here's the JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= fupNewImage.ClientID %>").bind("change", function () {
        var fSize = ((this.files[0].size) / 1024).toFixed(2);
        if (fSize <= 200) {
            $("#fupSize").html('Good file size: ' + fSize + " kb  Width=? and Height=?" ); // ? denotes the actual value to be put.
        }
        //---------More cases
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

Thanks to  @Esailija

After a lot of searching I finally found a workout @ REF https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904008/1584140

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    $("#<%= fupNewImage.ClientID %>").bind("change", function () {
        //================Changed Code===================
        var file, img;
        if ((file = this.files[0])) {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                var fSize = ((file.size) / 1024).toFixed(2);
                var WH = " Widht: " + this.width + "px & Height: " + this.height + "px";

                if (fSize <= 200) {
                    $("#fupSize").html('Good file size: ' + fSize + " kb" + WH);
                }
            };
            img.onerror = function () {
                alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
            };
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }
        //====================================
    });
});
```