# Jquery image and height display

Tags: jquery, image, height, width

```
<input type="file" class="test" name="vend_logo" id="vend_logo">

$('.test').bind('change', function() {
var file = files[0]
var img = new Image();
var width = img.width;alert(width);
});
```

I wanted to alert the image width and height been uploaded. how can i do this ? I have used `clientwidth` and also `naturalwidth` but it is not displaying the correct value.

Comment: why are you creating new image using `img = new Image();`?

Comment: that is not needed ?

Comment: $('.test').bind('change', function() {

   var width = this.files[0].width;
   alert(width);


});
 i have changed the code like this. but it is not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
$('.test').bind('change', function() {
  if (file = this.files[0]) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      var width = this.width;
      alert(width);
    };
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="test" name="vend_logo" id="vend_logo">
```

Reference : [Check image width and height before upload with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-on-upload-with-javascript)

Comment: @cd4xltech : glad to help you :)