# Find width and height uploaded image in canvas HTML5.(With file reader)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using HTML5 and fabric js for uploading multiple image in canvas. Right now i am uploading multiple image in canvas. But i want to find uploaded image width and height. I have seen one link [Check image width and height before upload with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-on-upload-with-javascript)

In this link not using file reader. But in my case using file reader.

```js
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
   document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change",function (e) {
   var file = e.target.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   console.log("reader   " + reader);
   reader.onload = function (f) {
   var data = f.target.result;
   fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
   var oImg = img.set({ width: 250, height: 200, angle: 0}).scale(0.9);
   canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
   var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
   var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
   });
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   });
```

```css
 canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
 <input type="file" id="file">
  <div style="">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jcubic is right about using an `<img>` tag, *(while there would be some ways to get this info without it)* but he is absolutely wrong in how he gets the image's dimensions.

`.clientWidth` and `.clientHeight` will return the computed width of the `<img>` element. You don't care about it, since what you are drawing on your canvas is the image contained in the `<img>`, not the `<img>` element itself.

What you need then is `.width` and .`height` properties or `.naturalWidth` and `.naturalHeight`.

```js
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change",function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  reader.onload = function () {
    var data = this.result;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = data;
    img.onload = function() {
      output.innerHTML = 'width: ' + img.width + '\n' +
        'height: ' + img.height;
    };
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file"/>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Can this be done with canvas instead of loading the image in a `img` tag? I'm using canvas for resizing the image, but I wonder if I could avoid the step of loading the src on a image

Answer (score 1):

You can create an img tag and get the dimensions from it.

```js
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change",function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = data;
    img.onload = function() {
      output.innerHTML = 'width: ' + img.width + '\n' +
        'height: ' + img.height;
    };
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file"/>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Why do we need to append it in DOM ?

Comment: @RayonDabre if you don't do this the width and height is 0.

Comment: We can get is using `img.width` once image is loaded right ?

Comment: @jcubic. Can we find width and height before upload image in canvas.

Comment: why do you use `.clientWidth`? `.width` will give you the width of the image. No need to append it to doc. If some css rules interact on evrey images, your values will be wrong

Comment: @Kaiido I thought it was needed, I've updated the code.