# How to get image width and height using JavaScript before upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

How to get image width and height using Javascript before upload? I tried to test my code, but it does not work. How can I achieve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/r78qkjba/1/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="offer_image_1" onchange="check_thumbnail_image_format_fn()" type="file" id="offer_image_1" />
<script>
    function check_thumbnail_image_format_fn() {
        var offer_image_1_data = document.getElementById("offer_image_1");
        var offer_image_1_data_file = offer_image_1_data.files[0];
        var offer_image_1_data_file_width = offer_image_1_data_file.width;
        var offer_image_1_data_file_height = offer_image_1_data_file.height;
        alert(offer_image_1_data_file_width);
        alert(offer_image_1_data_file_height);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML5 and the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)**

Here's the uncommented **working code snippet example**:

```js
window.URL    = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var elBrowse  = document.getElementById("browse"),
    elPreview = document.getElementById("preview"),
    useBlob   = false && window.URL; // `true` to use Blob instead of Data-URL

function readImage (file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var image  = new Image();
    image.addEventListener("load", function () {
      var imageInfo = file.name    +' '+
                      image.width  +'×'+
                      image.height +' '+
                      file.type    +' '+
                      Math.round(file.size/1024) +'KB';
      elPreview.appendChild( this );
      elPreview.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", imageInfo +'<br>');
    });
    image.src = useBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(file) : reader.result;
    if (useBlob) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(file); // Free memory
    }
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
}

elBrowse.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var files  = this.files;
  var errors = "";
  if (!files) {
    errors += "File upload not supported by your browser.";
  }
  if (files && files[0]) {
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      if ( (/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name) ) {
        readImage( file ); 
      } else {
        errors += file.name +" Unsupported Image extension\n";  
      }
    }
  }
  if (errors) {
    alert(errors); 
  }
});
```

```css
#preview img{height:100px;}
```

```html
<input id="browse" type="file"  multiple />
<div id="preview"></div>
```

---

Using an input and a div for the images preview area

```
<input id="browse" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

let's also use a CSS to keep the resulting images a reasonable height:

```
#preview img{ height:100px; }
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
window.URL    = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var elBrowse  = document.getElementById("browse"),
    elPreview = document.getElementById("preview"),
    useBlob   = false && window.URL; // `true` to use Blob instead of Data-URL


// 2.
function readImage (file) {

  // 2.1
  // Create a new FileReader instance
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader
  var reader = new FileReader();

  // 2.3
  // Once a file is successfully readed:
  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {

    // At this point `reader.result` contains already the Base64 Data-URL
    // and we've could immediately show an image using
    // `elPreview.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<img src='"+ reader.result +"'>");`
    // But we want to get that image's width and height px values!
    // Since the File Object does not hold the size of an image
    // we need to create a new image and assign it's src, so when
    // the image is loaded we can calculate it's width and height:
    var image  = new Image();
    image.addEventListener("load", function () {

      // Concatenate our HTML image info 
      var imageInfo = file.name    +' '+ // get the value of `name` from the `file` Obj
                      image.width  +'×'+ // But get the width from our `image`
                      image.height +' '+
                      file.type    +' '+
                      Math.round(file.size/1024) +'KB';

      // Finally append our created image and the HTML info string to our `#preview` 
      elPreview.appendChild( this );
      elPreview.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", imageInfo +'<br>');
    });

    image.src = useBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(file) : reader.result;

    // If we set the variable `useBlob` to true:
    // (Data-URLs can end up being really large
    // `src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAA...........etc`
    // Blobs are usually faster and the image src will hold a shorter blob name
    // src="blob:http%3A//example.com/2a303acf-c34c-4d0a-85d4-2136eef7d723"
    if (useBlob) {
      // Free some memory for optimal performance
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(file);
    }
  });

  // 2.2
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);  

}

// 1.
// Once the user selects all the files to upload
// that will trigger a `change` event on the `#browse` input
elBrowse.addEventListener("change", function() {

  // Let's store the FileList Array into a variable:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList
  var files  = this.files;
  // Let's create an empty `errors` String to collect eventual errors into:
  var errors = "";

  if (!files) {
    errors += "File upload not supported by your browser.";
  }

  // Check for `files` (FileList) support and if contains at least one file:
  if (files && files[0]) {

    // Iterate over every File object in the FileList array
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {

      // Let's refer to the current File as a `file` variable
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
      var file = files[i];

      // Test the `file.name` for a valid image extension:
      // (pipe `|` delimit more image extensions)
      // The regex can also be expressed like: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i
      if ( (/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name) ) {
        // SUCCESS! It's an image!
        // Send our image `file` to our `readImage` function!
        readImage( file ); 
      } else {
        errors += file.name +" Unsupported Image extension\n";  
      }
    }
  }

  // Notify the user for any errors (i.e: try uploading a .txt file)
  if (errors) {
    alert(errors); 
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope below code will help you.

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#offer_image_1").change(function (e) {
var file, img;
if ((file = this.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
});
```

You don't need to add onchange event at the input node.
This code is taken from 
[Check image width and height before upload with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-on-upload-with-javascript)