# How to get image height width in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I uploads the image, in the jQuery function;

```
$('body').on('change', '#file', function () {
```

By using `this.files[0]` I am getting image name and size. for this I am using.
`this.files[0].size` and `this.files[0].name`. But now I want to get height and width of image. How can I do that?

Comment: will this not work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-on-upload-with-javascript

Comment: No dear, its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution by myself, it is as follows,

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
 function imageIsLoaded(e) {
         var image = new Image();
         image.src = e.target.result;
         image.onload = function() {
              // access image size here 
              alert(this.width);
              alert(this.height);
         };
 };
```

as jquery dont know exact file type, so after Image type validation we can convert any image file to jQuery readable image, so jQuery can handle it as image. Hence for converting file to image we need reader.