# form upload image by FTP doesn't work, shows a white square instead of the image

Tags: php, image, ftp

If I try to upload an image... It shows me the root folder with the size but it shows me only a white square... Not the picture with the resolution...

**upload.php**

```
<?php require '../conx.php';  
session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION["userID"])){
    } else{
        header('Location: ../login.php');
        }
?>
<?php
$ftp_server = "ftp.xxxx.com";
$ftp_user_name = "xxxx@exemple.com";
$ftp_user_pass = "xxxxx";
$destination_file = "/public_html/lifestyle/imagini/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
echo "FTP connection has failed!";
echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
exit; 
} else {
echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $destination_file\n";
    header('Location: administrator/admin_index_lifestyle.php');
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $destination_file\n";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

**form**

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input name="file" type="file" />
  Upload foto in folderul lifestyle/imagini/ pentru ARTICOL
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File in lifestyle" />
</form>
```

If I try to see the picture using the absolute link, it shows me only a white square... not the image. If I use FtpZilla to upload the image it works... 
So there must be a problem in my form.

Comment: Any number of things could be wrong. Are you seeing any of your output messages?

Comment: i really don't recommend saving the file with it's original name, Stefan. this leaves you open to many facets of attack.

Comment: how? can you give me a exemple i am novice at codeing

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same issue. Solved by adding this attribute to `<input type="file">`:

```
accept="image/jpeg"
```

You can add some more types if you wish. Hope that helps

Comment: i change and work partial,now is other problem doesnt have the resolution original, and is like 250 pixeli only... so is showing very ugly the picture

Comment: @StefanJ., check the size with JS [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript). Then check it in PHP with _getimagesize()_ and give me both results. Not sure what the problem could be

Comment: how can you give me a exemple? i am beginner... in codeing

Comment: @StefanJ., if you are only a beginner, first read some books and documentation. Then improve your English, because it is really bad (don't want to insult you). Then search in the English part of the Net for the things I wrote before. And use your head, of course. I've already given you a link with JS example. As for getimagesize(), Google should be useful