# How to validate the image size of file input upload with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have the following input field of type 'file':

```
<input id="company_logo" name="company_logo" type="file" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg">
<img id="logo_preview" src="#" alt="Your Logo" />
```

I am using the following code to preview the uploaded image once a valid file has been selected:

```
$("#company_logo").change(function() {
            displayUploadedLogo(this);
        });

function displayUploadedLogo(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

            var file = input.files[0];
            var fileType = file["type"];
            var ValidImageTypes = ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];

            if ($.inArray(fileType, ValidImageTypes) > 0) {

                // If uploaded image is within array of valid image types
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    $('#logo_preview')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(75)
                        .height(75)
                        .css('display', 'block');
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            } else {
                // Uploaded file is not an image
                $('#logo_preview').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }
    }
```

This bascially works, but I would like to additionally validate that the selected image has a **specific image size** (e.g. 200 x 200 pixels). Images that do not comply with the size requirements (larger or smaller), should be rejected with an error messages.

Would appreciate your advice how to go about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Comment: @AdamWolski note that the question was about the dimensions of the image (and not the file-size).

Comment: I am not looking for file size. I would like to validate image dimensions.

Comment: Och, sorry you're right, well then duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check image width and height before upload with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript)