# Upload the image only after validating the image size in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

Here is my code to check the image size and width that matches the criteria

```
im.identify(req.files.image,function (err,features) {      
   //console.log(features);                                
    if(features.width<1000){                               
        console.log('need bigger size');                   
    }                                                      
  });  
 //upload code here
 beginUpload();
```

Since its asynchronous the `beginUpload()` function is invoked early so how can i check the image size synchronously.
ie i want to upload the image that pass the size criteria

Comment: But i want the image type, its not providing it

Comment: There is no other solution instead of using the above two packages??

Answer (score 1):

Call your function in a promise.

When your identify() function is done, the promise (then()) will be execute.

Try this :

```
im.identify(req.files.image,function (err,features) {      
    //console.log(features);                                
    if(features.width<1000){                   
        console.log('need bigger size');
        //stop the function to don't execute then()
        return false;                 
    }                                                   
}).then(function() {
    //upload code here
    beginUpload();
});
```

Comment: Let me try yr answer

Comment: I got this error  im.identify(...).then is not a function

Answer (score 0):

@Maitre Manuel correctly notes that the UI can implement a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to ensure the asynchronous validation happens before posting.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript) discusses some of the code you can use for the check itself. Eg, to determine image width on the client side before posting.