# Form is not submitting on giving validations for image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote validation for checking image dimensions in jquery(not written by me,copied from stackoverflow).whenever I upload current image,then it goes to else block but not submitted.
The script is working fine.But not submitting the form.Earlier I submitted the form without image validation then form submitted successfully.Whenever I wrote validation,Form is not submitted.
In form tag,I return the value of submitfunction() on submit event.
Here is the code:
**Here is the script code:**

```
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        function submitproject(){
                     var file, img;
        if ((file = $('#picture')[0].files[0])) {
                            img = new Image();
                            img.onload = function() {
                                if(this.width!=572 && this.height!=379){
                                    alert("Please select appropriate picture.(only  572X379 is allowed)");
                                    return false;
                                }
                                else
                                    {
                                    return true;*//to submit the form on correct image dimensions*
                                    }

                            };
                            img.onerror = function() {
                                alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
                            };
                            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);


                        }


                    }
```

Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show us the code (and the link where you got it), it can help us a bit !

Comment: You have to show us the code. Without that we don't know what your problem is.

Comment: Please post sample code for better response.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console ?

Comment: I copied from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript.

Comment: no..@ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ