# Get the file object from Simple Ajax Uploader plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm using this simple AJAX uploader and when I upload an image I need to get the dimensions of the image file before uploading. 
https://www.lpology.com/code/ajaxuploader/docs.php

Right now it only gives filename, extension and file size. No way to get the selected file object.
Under `onSubmit` method using `alert(JSON.stringify(this, null, 4))` gave the following output in which anything in it cannot be used to find the image's dimensions.

Viewing the source, I could find the file input as shown below.

```
<input name="uploadfile" multiple="" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 480px; font-family: sans-serif; cursor: pointer; height: 100%; z-index: 16777270;" type="file">

{
    "_opts": {
        "url": "/wps/web/app_dev.php/ajax-upload",
        "dropzone": "",
        "dragClass": "",
        "form": "",
        "overrideSubmit": true,
        "cors": false,
        "withCredentials": false,
        "progressUrl": false,
        "sessionProgressUrl": false,
        "nginxProgressUrl": false,
        "multiple": true,
        "multipleSelect": true,
        "maxUploads": 3,
        "queue": true,
        "checkProgressInterval": 500,
        "keyParamName": "APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS",
        "sessionProgressName": "PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS",
        "nginxProgressHeader": "X-Progress-ID",
        "customProgressHeaders": {},
        "corsInputName": "XHR_CORS_TARGETORIGIN",
        "allowedExtensions": [
            "jpg",
            "jpeg",
            "gif"
        ],
        "accept": "",
        "maxSize": 1024,
        "name": "uploadfile",
        "data": {},
        "noParams": true,
        "autoSubmit": true,
        "multipart": true,
        "method": "POST",
        "responseType": "json",
        "debug": false,
        "hoverClass": "hover",
        "focusClass": "focus",
        "disabledClass": "",
        "customHeaders": {},
        "encodeHeaders": true,
        "autoCalibrate": true,
        "button": null
    },
    "_queue": [
        {
            "id": "a1696f281-6b04-442e-887c-fba95a148d1f",
            "file": {},
            "name": "1.jpg",
            "ext": "jpg",
            "btn": {},
            "size": 25
        }
    ],
    "_active": 0,
    "_disabled": false,
    "_maxFails": 10,
    "_progKeys": {},
    "_sizeFlags": {},
    "_btns": [
        {}
    ],
    "_manDisabled": false,
    "_overBtn": {},
    "_input": {}
}
```

Comment: You are just over complicating your problem. Target the field and get its **width:** `document.querySelector('#fieldId').naturalWidth` and **height:** `document.querySelector('#fieldId').naturalHeight()`. The plugin you mentioned doesn't provide an API to get the dimensions of selected image file (which IMHO is reasonable as it supports multiple filetypes).

Comment: Obviously. But this $("input[name='uploadfile']").naturalHeight() does not work.

Comment: sorry, my bad... it should be `document.querySelector('#fieldId').naturalHeight`. it's not a function

Comment: Doesn't something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904008/1369473) address your problem?

Comment: These did not work.