# How do I restrict image uploads to a certain height and width?

Tags: jquery, html, image, file-upload

```
function filePreview (input) {
    if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#uploadForm + img').remove();
        $('#uploadForm').after('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="840" height="600" />');
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
  }

    $('#fileThumbnail').change(function() {
      filePreview(this);
    });
```

I am trying to preview the image but only accept images if they are of width:840px, height:600px no more and no less. and return a error to select an image of those exact dimensions

Comment: You can check image size on server end , For that please try to use ajax uploader and save image to specific directory only if it meets your resolution requirement.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript

Comment: @RahulSawant we cannot fully trust all browsers if we use client side solutions, To some extent javascript solution is useful, But end users may use any kind of browsers. So I think server side checking will be an ideal solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to convert the file to [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) element to get the width and height before applying.

I also add this line `/(image\/)(jpeg|jpg|bmp|gif)/.test(input.files[0].type)` to check the file extension before converting (only images with extensions `jpef`, `jpg`, `bmp` and `gif` are accepted)

```js
function filePreview (input) {
        if(input.files && input.files[0] && /(image\/)(jpeg|jpg|bmp|gif)/.test(input.files[0].type)) {
        
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
              
              var image = new Image();
              
              image.onload = function () {
                // you can check the image width and height here
                var width = this.width;
                var height = this.height;
                
                if (width === 840 && height === 600) {
                  // code goes here...

                  // $('#uploadForm + img').remove();
                  // $('#uploadForm').after(this);
                }
                
                $('body').append(this);
              };
              
              image.src = this.result;
              
          }
          
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    
        $('#fileThumbnail').change(function() {
          filePreview(this);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" id="fileThumbnail" />
```

Comment: I dont get a preview of the image anymore

Comment: @LexSha You can start to upload using the code inside the `if` block: `if (width === 840 && height === 600) { ... }`. Another images which don't have this size can't be uploaded.

Comment: I added this if `(width === 840 && height === 600) {
                    // code goes here...
  
                    $('#uploadForm + img').remove();
                    $('#uploadForm').after('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="840" height="600" />');
                  }`

Comment: @LexSha Nope. You can check my code again. I've replaced `<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="840" height="600" />` with `this`

Comment: @LexSha `$('#uploadForm').after(this)` is just enough.

Comment: `if (width === 840 && height === 600) {
                    // code goes here...
  
                    $('#uploadForm + img').remove();
                    $('#uploadForm').after(this);
                  }` still no preview

Comment: @LexSha Have you tried to convert the file to `Image` element like I have mentioned above? `var image = new Image(); image.onload..... image.src....` All of them are inside `reader.onload` function