# How to get width and height in PHP before upload?

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to check for the width and height of an image before uploading it and do some checking but after much Google research I came out with this, which also doesn't work.

```
        $tmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmp);
```

The error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS Blog\NewPost.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS Blog\NewPost.php(12): getimagesize('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS Blog\NewPost.php on line 12
```

Here's some of the HTML:

```
<form action="NewPost.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p class="text-warning" style="margin-bottom: 7px;">Select Thumbnail:</p>
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input class="custom-file-input" type="file" name="image" id="ImageInput" value="" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
                                    <label for="ImageInput" class="custom-file-label">Upload Image</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</form>
```

Does anyone know how to check for the width and height before uploading it?
I have been struggling for 2 days now with this problem.
Thanks very much!

PS: Using the newest version of XAMPP. And PHP 8.

Comment: Before upload or sending request to your server it is not possible to learn it with PHP. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading you must use JavaScript.

After uploading use PHP's GD class
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php