# How to put a filter to a minimum image size

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

Ok, so I'm making a website where you can upload images, however the images will fit a specific container, and if an image has a smaller size than the container, it will stretch and lose quality, this means I want something like those social medias when you're going to put a profile picture or a wallpaper and then comes a message saying your image is too small the resolution should be 1080×720... Something like it, it just need to stop the user to do it. I aprecciate any help.

I dont think the code is necessary since it isn't something specific.

(If necessary script I would prefer JS or PHP)

I tried to research but didn't find anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check image width and height before upload with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Check with PHP the size of image:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Then just stop the process if the media don¡t fit the requirements.

Comment: If you use PHP to check it, they need to first fully upload the file. If you use JS, you can check it before they upload it, saving everyone time and bandwidth.

Comment: How can you do it in JS?